# Cannot call Property for the property 'xxx' on entity type 'yyy' because it is configured as a navigation property?

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have the following model in a .Net core 2.0 application (Asp.net core web api 2.0)

```
public class AddressPasscode
{
    [Key] // Key attribute doesn't work so I need to set it in OnModelCreating
    public SqlBytes Address { get; set; }
    public int Passcode { get; set; }
}
```

The following code is in DB context

```
    public DbSet<AddressPasscode> AddressPasscodes { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<AddressPasscode>().HasKey(e => e.Address);
    }
```

However, this a runtime error on `modelBuilder.Entity<AddressPasscode>().HasKey(e => e.Address);`

> InvalidOperationException: Cannot call Property for the property 'Address' on entity type 'AddressPasscode' because it is configured as a navigation property. Property can only be used to configure scalar properties.

Comment: You can't use `SqlBytes` type as a primary key.

Comment: What type should I use? string?

Comment: How do I know? I don't know what you're trying to do or what data you are storing.

Comment: I'm storing the address of Ethereum, which is a 20-byte value. Which type can it be in EF? Thanks.

Comment: You might be able to use a byte array (i.e. `byte[]`) but you might be better off with a string anyway.

Comment: OK, thanks. I will use string. It will be passed to a webapi call like `localhost:29238/api/passcode/.....`. However, not sure if all the bytes can be present as a string to generate the URL?

Comment: A URL needs to be a string. Look at any Ethereum website that shows you transactions, you will see the format they use there.

Comment: To add more about the exception (apart from PK error DavidG pointed out), SqlBytes is not a scalar type in EF Core so it will expand it as if its an entity type. Essentially making Address a navigation property. You cannot call HasKey on a navigation in EF Core.